# Extract key=value substring with regex

Tags: java, regex

I would like to extract the value of `id` from a string. The string contains key-value pairs and the pairs are comma separated (no commas in actual values).

I would like to extract the value of `id` key, which is 123456789 in the sample input string below. The value of `id` is always a number.

```
reference="edd63cd8-cdf5-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002",args="one two three",id=123456789,someField="data",someOtherId=567890
```

How can I achieve this with regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match `id=` followed by a sequence of non-comma characters.

```java
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\bid=([^,]+)").matcher(str);
if (m.find()) System.out.println(m.group(1));
else System.out.println("No match");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Positive Lookbehind with numeric matching. Try the expression

```
(?<=id=)\d+
```

**Positive Lookbehind:**

`(?<=...)` Ensures that the given pattern will match, ending at the current position in the expression. The pattern must have a fixed width. Does not consume any characters.

In this case you case, you can use `(?<=id=)\d+`.

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/gifIkf/1

and the code generated from https://regex101.com/r/gifIkf/1

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "(?<=id=)\\d+";
        final String string = "reference=\"edd63cd8-cdf5-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002\",args=\"one two three\",id=123456789,someField=\"data\",someOtherId=567890\n";
        
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```